# I created an openlayer map that I want to add to a Flask web application, how to proceed?

Tags: flask, openlayers

I am a beginner in both tools, I learned basic flask to be able to create a web app and worked around with openlayers dosumentations until I achieved the map I wanted. [world map with selection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTjBo.png)

My objective is to create a web app with one of its pages the map I created, how can I do that with flask ?

I don't know if there is a need for the map code to be put in here,please let me know.

Comment: Please any clue on this one ? any ressources ? I couldn't find a helpful doc on the web